# Merge two .sqlite files on OSX

Tags: database, macos, sqlite, merge

So what would one do to **merge two .sqlite database files** (like somedata.sqlite and someOtherData.sqltie) with **identical schema** into one .sqlite file on the Mac?

I'm guessing this could be done in Terminal, and if someone would describe the steps in detail that would be super cool!

Answer (score 2):

If the two files have the exact same schema you could dump the files and import them in a new db.

```
sqlite3 database1.db '.dump' >> tmp.txt
sqlite3 database2.db '.dump' >> tmp.txt
sqlite3 database3.db '.import tmp.txt'
```

I'm not in OSX so maybe is not like this but you get the idea.

Comment: didn't work for me, says invalid arguments: 'import'

Comment: @spuder try this, open the db with `sqlite3 name.db` and then `.import filename.txt` double check the name of the txt file where the sql code is.

Comment: The .import command doesn't work on OSX. It requires a table argument after the file. So...useless. Anyone know how to make this work on OS X?

Comment: @user2872895 You could always use vagrant and run a virtual machine on mac osx to get this to work :)